# MongoDb aggregation is very slow with match and sort on +1M records

Tags: mongodb, performance, aggregation-framework, query-optimization

I got a few millions of records in a `tweets` collection.

Records are of this type:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("611bcfb338e50b6840fa441f"),
    "hour" : ISODate("2021-07-30T05:00:00.000Z"),
    "searches" : [
        ObjectId("611bc957153268001df01f14"),
        ObjectId("6139aaa017d1da001c5ac385")
    ]
}
```

I have indexes created on

- `searches`
- `hour`
- `searches` and `hour` -> not use if it's needed but I did it

I try to make a request through an aggregation like so

```
[
    {
        "$match": {
            "searches": ObjectId("6139aaa017d1da001c5ac385")
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "searches": 1,
            "hour": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "$sort": {
            "hour": -1
        }
    },
    {
        "$limit": 1
    }
]
```

But it takes very long (17s)

If I remove the `$sort` stage, it takes only 1s

I want to know if it's possible to make this query faster WITH the sort stage as it's mandatory in my case.

I also believe it should take a lot less than that.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you have an index on `{hour:-1, searches:1}`?

Comment: Thank you very much, I found out about descending indexes only today after years of using mongo ‍♂️ and it works a lot faster.

Comment: It's not faster because it is descending, it is faster because the sort field comes before the multi-key field.

Comment: I'm sorry @Joe I don't understand your last comment:
I first match the search
then sort in hour descending
So I'm not sure what you mean by "the sort field comes before the multi-key field"

Thanks again

Comment: In the data the `searches` field contains an array, which means each document will have more than one key in the index, i.e. multi-key.  An index can only be used for sorting if it can be guaranteed that the index scan will encounter the matching documents in sorted order, so the sort key `hour` must precede the multi-key field `searches` when building the index.  MongoDB can use an index in either forward or reverse direction, so the direction of the sort won't make a difference.